# linux audio not working / linux drivers for chromebook

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, chromebook

So I installed pearl os on my chromebook (model cb3-131 / c730) and the audio doesn't work. Yes i have tried different types (ubuntu, zorin os etc) and the audio didn't work on them either. If there any console command to type in or any drivers for it? Yes, i have tried these posts about you need to type in this then this then it will work, it didn't work. Like the alsa sound commands didn't work...

edit:

the console

```
                      byt-max98090
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd0914000 irq 264
myname@myname-computer:~$ aplay amixer
amixer: No such file or directory
```

also btw, none of them give out audio

Comment: First step is to type `cat /proc/asound/cards` from the command line and edit your question with the output. This works even if the packages for the ALSA tools (`aplay`, `amixer`, etc.) are not installed for whatever distribution you are using. Randomly switching between distributions won't necessarily install the tools or fix your problem; stick with one distro and figure out step by step what is wrong. Based on what doesn't work you can then take actions to fix it, like installing packages for missing commands.

Comment: right, i put in the post of what is says, now what?

Comment: That tells us that (1) you forgot the first line in the output, (2) you have at least two soundcards, so the kernel drivers work in principle, and (3) that `aplay` is installed properly (`amixer` is a different command, `aplay amixer` doesn't make sense). So next steps are (1) read `man aplay`, (2) find a wav file and use `aplay` to output it on both cards, (3) read `man amixer`, (4) run `amixer contents` for both cards and check if anything is muted that shouldn't be, and while you are at it, (5) run `pavucontrol` and see if you've Pulseaudio installed.

Comment: Depending on what works and what doesn't work we can then narrow down to where the problem is.

Comment: 1. i didn't see the , i aplay, amixer. 2. I have no clue of what im looking at. When i do `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` nothing installs so I think i have that. But in the command of where i type `pavucontrol` it doesn't come up. Also in the audio, everything says it's unplugged...

Comment: If you continue to just randomly do things without understanding what you are doing, or without even explaining exactly what you did and what the results/errors are, debugging this will be very difficult. You'll *have* to sit down on your posterior and do some reading; in the end, the only one who has access to the information is you, so the only one who can find out what's wrong and fix it is you. There is no "just type the following commands verbatim and all will be good, never mind what they do"; that's not how it works.

Comment: Take a look at the Mr. Chromebox site.  I recall there are certain models that have audio problems.  You should be able to find out if yours if one of those: https://mrchromebox.tech/